# Custom camera for all supported device

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm working on 1 project where it requires custom camera with flash,back/front camera,capture and save image. I want custom camera to be working on device (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) can anyone help regarding this? I tried some library as well but having issues in support version. Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score -1):

you can use this library 
[Annca](https://github.com/memfis19/Annca)

Comment: Thanks @vivek mahajan. I didn't use Annca library yet. Let me check